# After the GPS location has changed, how to retreive the new gps coordiantes?

Tags: azure-maps

Using the npm package `azure-maps-control`. After the user drags around in the map. I would like to upgrade the points of intrest using a API call.  For this i found multiple events. It looks like that the `sourcedata` event can be used. Unfortunately after dragging i need the new GPS locations. How do i retrieve those?

Comment: Can you provide more details, it is not clear what you are trying to do? Are do you want to retrieve the center coordinate of the map as it is moved? By upgrade points of interest, are you trying to load more points of interest after the map has moved, either from the Azure Maps search service or some other data set?

Comment: > Are do you want to retrieve the center coordinate of the map as it is moved? 

Correct, I am trying to add more points from a azure cognitive search result. As i see it now i would like to have this information in the  global store. This is the reason i would like to know the new GPS location so a search result can be triggerd.

Answer (score 1):

For your scenario you will most likely want to wait until the user has stopped moving the map before making a request to a service to retrieve custom data since doing this while the map moves would potentially generate tens of requests per second. What you will want to do is monitor the `moveend` event of the map by doing something like `map.events.add('moveend', yourCallbackFunction)`. When this event fires, you can then retrieve the center position of the map using `map.getCamera().center`. Here is a code sample from the Azure Maps team that does all of this and a bit more: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/?sample=Load%20POIs%20as%20the%20map%20moves This sample makes multiple requests when the moveend event fires as the service it calls returns a max of a 100 results at a time, and this sample steps through and pulls in additional results.